# Windows server 2008 download unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, windows-server-2008, webclient

I am downloading xml file from the server. It is a SSIS project using VS2008. Its working fine in the local computer but when i am using the same code in the server. I am getting an error. `Unable to connect to the remote server`

This is my code to download the file. The Url has username and password.

```
  string url = "https://test.openseas.wlcl.com.au:8888/cruise/PA/priceSummary?AgentId=DIRECTAU&format=xml";
  WebClient mySSISWebClient = new WebClient();

  mySSISWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
  mySSISWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
  mySSISWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;

  // To save the file (and replace the existing file)
  mySSISWebClient.DownloadFile(url , Dts.Variables["User::LocalSourceFile"].Value.ToString());
```

The above code is working fine locally but not in the server. Anyone can help me why it is not working in the server. Is it the firewall issue because if i just type the URL(https://test.openseas.wlcl.com.au:8888/cruise/PA/priceSummary?AgentId=DIRECTAU&format=xml) on my browser i get the error . `this connection is untrusted`.  Any one can help me that would be really great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Showing "this connection is untrusted" in the browser is due to the invalid certificate on the ssl server, thus it has nothing to do with firewall. Additionally, returning true of ServerCertificateValidationCallback ignore "untrusted" problem. So, in normal cases, it has to work fine.

Can you describe more in detail about "but NOT in the server"?

Comment: in the server means i am getting this error in Windows server 2008 @SeongTaeJeong

Comment: Let's clean up. If you visit the url in the browser in windows server 2008, you get an error "this connection is untrusted", but your application in the same machine get an error "Unable to connect to the remote server"?

Comment: when i visit the url (my local machine or windows server 2008) i get the error "this connection is untrusted". The code i typed in my question is working fine in my local machine but when i run this in the windows server 2008 i get the error  " unable to connect to the remote server" @SeongTaeJeong